# Difference between .NET's System.Type.GenericTypeArguments and System.Type.GetGenericArguments()

Tags: .net, generics, system.type

Why does the .NET Framework provide both

```
System.Type.GenericTypeArguments
```

and

```
System.Type.GetGenericArguments()
```

which both return the type arguments (both as a `Type[]`) of a given generic type ?

Seems the property and the method expose the very same functionality, meaning the API's interface has redundant/duplicate functionalities ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The [`GenericTypeArguments` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh227083%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an empty array if the type is a generic type defintion, while the [`GetGenericArguments` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an array with the types for the generic arguments.
- The `GenericTypeArguments` property was added in framework 4.5.

The `GenericTypeArguments` property is actually implemented to call `GetGenericArguments` when the type is an implementation of a generic type:

```
public virtual Type[] GenericTypeArguments {
  get {
    if (IsGenericType && !IsGenericTypeDefinition){
      return GetGenericArguments();
    } else {
      return Type.EmptyTypes;
    }
  }
}
```

Source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs,0aa31a7de47b9dc7

Comment: Really? That's weird... if GenericTypeArguments's purpose is like you say, then should it not be a boolean ?! What's the use of returning an empty array - for the purpose of stating whether a type is a generic type definition or not ?!

Comment: @Veverke: It returns an array of types if the type is an implementation of a generic type. `typeof(List<>).GenericTypeArguments` returns an empty array, `typeof(List<int>).GenericTypeArguments` returns an array containing `typeof(int)`, and `typeof(List<>).GetGenericArguments()` returns an array containing the type for the generic argument `T`.

Comment: oh... this is clearer, although it is not an easy task to stay on track with these names...

Comment: I forgot .NET became open source last november... I thought of searching for the code, but thought it did not happen yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It will become more obvious when you look at the *Version Information* documentation in the MSDN articles for these members.  The GenericTypeArguments property is supported for WinRT (aka Windows Store apps), the GetGenericArguments() method is not.

WinRT caused many changes in .NET Framework version 4.5, most however are not that obvious.  The *language projection* built into the framework covers up most of the fundamental type system differences and hides the fact that WinRT is COM-based at its core.  Not if you use Reflection however, it had to be tackled very differently.